# How to get bluetooth radio handle?

Tags: bluetooth

I need to perform IOCTL commands on the bluetooth radio for which i need a handle for it. 
I do realize that we could use the BluetoothFindFirstRadio function for this. But is there any other way to do this?

I have to run this app on an ARM platform which does not support the BluetoothFindFirstRadio function as it does not have the required extern assembly. But it does allow IOCTLs which obviously require a handle.

Comment: Why do you need another way?

Comment: I have to run this app on an ARM platform which does not support the BluetoothFindFirstRadio function as it does not have the required extern assembly. But it does allow IOCTLs which obviously require a handle.